# Why am I geting an invalid XML error in my Phing build.xml?

Tags: xml, continuous-integration, jenkins, phing

It says XML not well formed when I highlight over the unzip tag. The complete file is at: https://github.com/reload/phing-drupal-template/blob/master/build.xml (line 255)

What am I doing wrong?

```
<httpget url="${jslint4java.url}"
             dir="${jslint4java.dir}"
             proxy="${phing.httpget.proxy}/>
    <unzip file="${jslint4java.dir}/${jslint4java.zipfile}"
           todir="${jslint4java.dir}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing a quotation mark in `proxy="${phing.httpget.proxy}/>`. It should be `proxy="${phing.httpget.proxy}"/>`

**Edit**

There are some other issues as well, but I don't know the correct format. The offending lines are:

```
698  <isset property="drupal.uri">
743  <echo msg="You must set the drupal.uri property to get simpletests working.">
973  <isset property="drupal.make.rewritebase">
1209 <httpget url="${patch.url}"
         dir="${project.toolsdir}"
         proxy="${phing.httpget.proxy}/>
```

The first three can be fixed by adding a `/` before the closing `>`. The last one is the same as the first one (missing `"`). However, while this should make the file valid XML it may not be the correct syntax.